# Sort/Edit A File with Unix Commands?

Tags: sorting, unix, filter

I have a 300MB file that looks like this:

> Item   Item
>   Item   Item
>   Item2  Something
>   ...    ...

It's basically two columns going all the way down. So each row has two entries. The columns are separated by [this character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/cfgfghhhh%09har/0009/index.htm) (Alt +0009) which I believe is the "tab" character. The rows are sorted alphanumerically by the first column entry.

Basically what I need to do with this file is produce a new file with it like so:

- First, sort the rows alphanumerically by the *second* column entry.
- Second, remove all rows where the second column entry never appears in the file as one of the first column entries.

So for example:

> A B
>   A C
>   A E
>   C A
>   E F

Goes to

> C A
>   A B
>   A C
>   A E
>   E F

then finally to

> C A
>   A C
>   A E

(Note that in this example I used a space character instead of a tab character to separate the columns, in the file I'm trying to sort the columns are separated by the tab character (Alt +0009))

So how would I go about doing this using Unix commands?

Comment: This seems a little too specialized, you might be better off writing a program yourself

Comment: Why does the `A E` row get removed, even though `E F` is in the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first operation can be handled using the `sort` utility (with the `-k` flag set appropriately). The second operation is more complex and will likely need a custom script of some kind to be implemented.